# How do I set the lifetime of a return value as the lifetime of the variable I move into it?

Tags: rust

I am trying to teach myself some rust, and have written something that looks like:

```
let args:Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
let parsed = parser::sys(args.as_slice());
```

...

```
pub fn sys<'a>(args:&'a [String]) -> Parsed<'a> {
  parsed(args)
}
```

where `parsed` is a function that parses and loads configs.

This works fine. Now I am trying to abstract away explicitly calling `env::args()` and hide it in the call to `sys` , so I write a new version of `sys`

```
pub fn sys<'a>() -> Parsed<'a> {
  let args:Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
  parsed(args.as_slice())
}
```

And this fails with:

```
error: `args` does not live long enough
src/test.rs:66      parsed(args.as_slice())
```

I think the error is because there's no way for compiler to infer that I want the lifetime of this newly created struct to be the lifetime of the variable I want to move this into. Is this correct? How would I annotate the lifetime on this return value/fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I think the error is because there's no way for compiler to infer that I want the lifetime of this newly created struct to be the lifetime of the variable I want to move this into.

Actually, no.

The error is because you are trying to create references into the variable `args` which will no longer be valid after you return from `sys` since `args` is a local variable and thus is dropped at the end of `sys`.

If you wish to use references, you could supply `sys` with a `&'a mut Vec<String>` (empty), fill it in `sys`, and return references to it:

```
pub fn sys<'a>(args: &'a mut Vec<String>) -> Parsed<'a> {
    *args = env::args().collect();
    parsed(args.as_slice())
}
```

which guarantees that `args` outlive the `sys` call. This will borrow `args` for the lifetime of the result.

Another solution is to do away with `'a` and simply have `Parsed` own its elements rather than have references to them; however without the definition of `Parsed` I cannot advise how best to do so.

Comment: Is there no way to "move" args out of sys, e.g. like std:move or copy elision. The following works, but there too I am assigning to a local variable, but somehow I think the compiler knows how to move it out: 
  pub fn contents(source:&String) -> Vec<String> {

    let mut reader = BufferedReader::new(File::open( &Path::new(source)));
    reader.lines().map(|l| l.unwrap()).collect()
  }

Comment: @sgldiv `Reader::lines` is an `Iterator<Item=String>`, not an `Iterator<Item=&'a str>`. You return a `Vec<String>` which has full ownership of all data that's returned. There is nothing from which the return value is borrowed and which the compiler magically silently moves around.