# struct lifetime of field from another field

Tags: rust

I'm parsing some text and would like to store a Vec of slices of it.

```
struct Word<'a> {
    word: &'a str,
    // other_stuff
}
struct Text<'a> {
    text: String,
    words: Vec<Word<'a>>,
    // other_things
}
```

I don't know how to say the lifetime of `word` is the same as `text`.
Is something like this possible?

Comment: As a side note, you're probably better off using a the owned type `String` in `Word`

Comment: I don't think I understand the question, are you looking for something like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ffd01f8bd7f58504e5ba2417e5cd2b9e ?

Comment: @ÖmerErden OP wants the lifetime of text to be the same as words, so to purely express the intent `text: 'a + String`. I  don't think that's possible.

Comment: Possible in this way: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=65fcc913c454fd927b6cd1a85b267bdd

Comment: @ÖmerErden 's solution and variants are the usual idiomatic ones. An alternative if you want an owned structure is to store byte indices, not references but you must be careful to avoid bugs

Comment: @OmerErden more like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=94c738fd4a62b9f23a1273d5ab26ede2

Comment: @Adamarla Word holding the indices instead of the reference. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f8b181a19e0e3315464a1ceab49527e4

Comment: Yes, using indices works, but that is what `The Book` recommends to avoid: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html

Comment: @Adamarla `text` is owned by the function's scope then moved out by returning. This means `text`'s lifetime will always be greater than the function's scope.  So that is not possible but i would implement the idea like this : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7a45af5a80855226a94aeaba68fff428

Comment: @mcarton can you also add this as a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672190/how-do-i-set-the-lifetime-of-a-return-value-as-the-lifetime-of-the-variable-i-mo, IMO this is the real target for dupe.